# JQuery within PHP: How can I keep the browser from inserting a closing tag too early?

Tags: php, jquery

The output of this code:

```
<?php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> $('#query-info').append('<div class=\"well\">')</script>";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $entry)
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> $('#query-info').append('". $key . ": " . $entry . "<br />')</script>";
    }
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> $('#query-info').append('</div>')</script>";
?>
```

is:

```
<div class="well"></div>
itemID: 1
<br>
</div>
```

Note the extra unwanted (first) closing div.

Comment: I think what you're referring to is Chrome's habit of trying to "fix" your html. The only solution to that is to write valid HTML. Always.

Comment: You don't need to put the answer in your question - the selected answer is visible below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.append` can only append HTML nodes, it can't just append opening or closing tags.

Have PHP generate the entire `<div>`, then `.append` the whole thing.

```
<?php
    $HTML = '<div class="well">';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $entry)
    {
        $HTML .= "$key: $entry<br/>";
    }
    $HTML .= '</div>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">$("#query-info").append("'.json_encode($HTML).'");</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Better hope $HTML doesn't have any quotes in it. That should really be passed through json_encode() first.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript doesn't append strings to HTML, it appends fully-formed DOM nodes/elements; instead of appending the opening, then a new element and *then* a closing tag, append an element and then append a child, or children, to that newly-added node:

```
var newDiv = $('<div />', {'class' : 'well'}),
    otherDiv = $('<div />', {'class' : 'somethingElse'});
newDiv.appendTo('#query-info');
otherDiv.appendTo(newDiv);
```

The above will result in something like the following:

```
<div id="query-info">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="somethingElse"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking in terms of HTML, but the code is operating in terms of the DOM.  `.append('<div class=\"well\">')` will add an entire div, not just a string of text.  You need to add things as a child of that div.

```
var div = $('<div class=\"well\">').appendTo("#query-info");

//in the loop - add content to the div.well
div.append('". $key . ": " . $entry . "<br />');
```

You should use PHP to write HTML or jQuery to construct the DOM, but you probably should not be using PHP to write your jQuery.

Comment: `.append` returns the original node, not the newly inserted one.  Try `.appendTo` instead.

Comment: I found that .appendTo didn't work at all, whereas .append did: `echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var infoDiv = $('#query-info').appendTo('<div class=\"well\">')</script>";` Have I made a mistake?

Comment: The div should be appended to `#query-info`, not the other way around

Comment: @RosePerrone: `appendTo` uses the opposite parameters of `append`. It's `newElement.appendTo(currentElement)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call that jquery append function like that, it automatically will create a full node as you are seeing.  What you probably want to do in your case is output all your HTML to a javascript string variable and then append it like this:

```
<?php
    $js_inner_html = '';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $entry) {
        $js_inner_html .= $key . ': ' . $entry . '<br />';
    }
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#query-info').append('<div class="well"><?php echo $js_inner_html; ?></div>');
</script>
```

Comment: I think you'd need to embed the js in php and not vice versa.

Comment: I am guessing that since he is directly echoing out the javascript in his example that this is a page that has HTML on it as well.  Personally I think it cleaner (both on the script you are editing and in the resulting source code) to render large block of HTML without using PHP.  Here the only thing I am doing is outputting hte final "innerHTML" values within the script block from PHP.

Comment: PHP is server-side and js is client-side, so the PHP will render before the js. The embedded PHP may not get evaluated.

Comment: @RosePerrone The resulting source code in the browser would have the full $js_inner_html string inside of it.  The browser would have no idea if this source was generated dynamically from PHP or was just a static script block.